# Correctly using GetFolder to grab a path for SaveToFile

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use GetFolder() to grab a filepath that I can save using save to file and I keep getting a runtime error 3004 write to file failed, the problem is that the file still saves, however it saves outside of the folder that the path should be leading to from the getfolder. The folder I keep grabbing with getfolder is named Test in my documents file. The created document appears with the same name right next to the test folder instead of inside of it. Is this what is supposed to happen?Speaking of how it is named, it has the name of the file which would be test, in front of the name I want so the file is named TestNameIWant, is there something that I can do about this?

```
Dim BaseDirectory As String
BaseDirectory = GetFolder()
If (BaseDirectory = vbNullString) Then
MsgBox "No Folder Selected" < vbExclamation, "Error"
End If
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
objStream.Write("Testing" & vbLf)
projectName = "NameIwant"
FullPath = BaseDirectory & projectName & ".xml"
objStream.SaveToFile FullPath, 1
objStream.Close
```

I am expecting the file to save to a specific location and I keep getting Run Time Error 3004 Write To File Failed.

Comment: Did you try `Msgbox FullPath` to make sure it's what you expect?  Do you have write permissions on that folder?

Comment: Oh wow, I forgot to add a "\" so that it took the folder instead of just leaving it as C:\Users\Hakon\Documents\TestNameIwant.xml, I got it to change to FullPath = BaseDIrectory & "\" & projectName & ".xml". Does the SaveToFile just take the data after the last \ and use that as the name for the file or is there more to it that I cant see from the program?

Comment: The last part of the path will be the filename provided you have the path separators correct.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I've been trying to understand the SaveToFile for a while!